# Dynamic text background with padding at end of line break, character count

Tags: php, drupal

I want to close out my old question start a new one with a better sample photo.
I am trying to add a transparent png background to some dynamic text with line breaks and give it 15 px padding at the end of each sentence when the line breaks. But this text does not have the br tag in the html code. I don’t want the background to be a square box. I uploaded a sample of what I have and what I am trying to get. I heard there is a php script that can count characters like strlen, count_chars, substr_count. Can anyone help me. My css is below. It’s a span tag around dynamic text that changes. This is a Drupal Views Slideshow and it changes every few seconds, the photo and the text.

[image: screenshot]

Below is the code in Drupal Views I used Tokens for the text that needs the padding the Token is called 'text'.

```
    .bluebackground
    {background-image:url(images/transparentback.png);}

    <div id="textbox">
    <span class="bluebackground">[text]</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need PHP, instead just use CSS.

```
.bluebackground {
  background-image:url(images/transparentback.png);
  padding: 15px; /* add 15px padding around entire box */
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that method only adds padding to the beginning and the end of the sentence, not after the break in the sentence. See the sample photo in my post.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had those separated on two lines to start with. You can automatically have them separated using a little plugin like this (https://github.com/jeremyharris/split_lines) and then use CSS to add padding. I don't recommend using PHP because it has no idea what the text widths are going to be, so MMM could be wider than iii and produce different results.

Comment: Thank you for this link @jeremyharris, I will test this today and post my results!

Comment: have you worked with Drupal before? I am having trouble implementing it into Drupal. Im not a Drupal expert. I think the function_splitHtmlWords section needs to go into the template.php file, the .js file needs to go into your themes/js folder and be called in the .info file. Then the html section needs to go into a node page and turn on php code input format. I am having trouble inserting the functions into the template.php file.

Comment: I have it working now. This is a great tool!! If I am seeing this correctly, each line slit is wrapped with a div tag now, right? 
I added your functions sections on the node page using php code input. By doing it this way the functions will only work on this node page. I need to make it work sitewide so adding the functions section to the template.php file would be the best way. Then I need to add the id and class example-1 and example to my Drupal Views only the paragraph I need split.

Comment: Is it okay if I post a link to your script on the Drupal.org forum and ask for help there on adding the function so it works site wide?

Comment: I see that it adds a div tag to each split sentence. I there a way to add a class or id to those divs so that this: <div>example of some text</div> can be this: <div id="sentence">example of some< text/div>

Comment: Not currently but I accept pull requests. Add the issue to github instead of discussing it here, cause it's more appropriate :) Also you can pretty easily target them via css if your parent has a class (say `<div class="bluebackground">` would target the lines via `.bluebackground > div`.

Comment: Also you could hack it by adding a tag option in the setup to be: `tag: 'div class="sentence"'`

Comment: Thank you @jeremyharris! I added a class to each div and now have text background color with padding at the end of sentence break even when the sentences are different lengths. Its exactly what I what I needed! Now I need to figure out how to add the 'functions' so that it works site-wide on this Drupal site. Right now I just added the functions to a node so that the this script will only work on this page. Drupal has a template.php where all functions are places and then every page can call on it.

Comment: Can this script be placed in a .js file and not directly on the page/html node.
<script type="text/javascript">
function cycleFade() {
...code...
</script>

Comment: Yep it can. It's just JS after all :) When you're confident you have it working go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: I added the 'script type javascript' section in the head section of my Drupal page template and it works! Im new to Stackoverflow and cant find the "accept the answer" button! I'm looking

Comment: hi @jeremyharris, I have this script working but I need it to work on divs that are not loaded when the dom is ready. I am using a jquery cycle slider. So the sentence split is working on the first cycle, but not on the others. Someone said to maybe use jQuery's .load() method and not the document ready method. Do you have and ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest posting that as a different question. This is getting pretty off topic. I'd be happy to help but the comments aren't the place to do so.